# Cron scheduled task ignored

Tags: linux, bash, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have set a specific cronjob (crontab -e), but it doesn't works like I thought. I don't get what's wrong.
Here is what I do (root cron):

```
@reboot /path/to/my_script.sh start
25 18 * * * halt
```

The first line as expected is running my_script.sh, but when time comes for the server to shutdown, nothing happen. Is the @reboot option made to work alone?

Comment: complete path to `halt`?

Comment: I'm trying, but I think I would have an error message in logs if that was the problem. Here I don't have anything.

Comment: Thanks devnull, that was it. I have to take the habit to use full path...

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in cron to run at shutdown. `@reboot` is meant to run the script on *start*

If you want to run a script at shutdown, you need to write an `initd` script and register it for the shutdown run level. The standard runlevel for `halt` is `0`, the run level for `restart` is `6`. I've verified this for Debian, Gentoo and Redhat systems but it seems to be true across *NIX systems. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_level) for more info.

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl, but you misunderstood it. I have a script running at boot time, but I also want to shutdown my server at an other time. When I ask if "@reboot" is made to work alone, in fact, I ask if the line with "@reboot" is cancelling the following lines.

Comment: No, why should it. Lines in a cron script don't get executed sequentially, they got executed on events.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the cron "@xxxxx" options, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: You are welcome, I have to admit that I not even knowed about them before. But the documentation is quite clear about them...